# How to add an "or" to Rules event?

Tags: 7, rules

Is it possible to add an "or" relation to a rule's event? I'd like to do exactly the same things when two different events took place. With an "or", I don't have to clone the whole rule.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just edit the rule and add another event to it. Reaction rules can have multiple associated events.